# Mounting MyCloud

Tags: 16.04, mount, samba, cifs

As I understand it, the [8TB WD MyCloud NAS - WDBCTL0080HWT-NESN](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01C7JIO5Y)  is SAMBA configured.  Faileted attempts to mount via cifs:

```
sudo mount -t cifs  //192.168.8.109/shares/Public /mnt/nas
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on //192.168.8.109/shares/Public, missing codepage or helper program, or other error (for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount.<type> helper program)
```

Questions

1. Is mount -t cifs incorrect to use with the MyCloud?
2. If correct, is there a problem with the syntax?
3. If syntax is correct, what other command line diagnostics can be
   performed?

Similar attempt made with smbfs instead of cifs:

```
sudo mount -t smbfs 192.168.8.109:/shares/Public  /mnt/nas username=root

Usage:  mount [-lhV]  mount -a [options]  mount [options] [--source] <source> | [--target] <directory>  mount [options] <source> <directory>  mount <operation> <mountpoint> [<target>]

Mount a filesystem.

Options:  -a, --all               mount all filesystems mentioned in
fstab  -c, --no-canonicalize   don't canonicalize paths  -f, --fake   
dry run; skip the mount(2) syscall  -F, --fork              fork off
for each device (use with -a)  -T, --fstab <path>      alternative
file to /etc/fstab  -i, --internal-only     don't call the
mount.<type> helpers  -l, --show-labels       show also filesystem
labels  -n, --no-mtab           don't write to /etc/mtab  -o,
--options <list>    comma-separated list of mount options  -O, --test-opts <list>  limit the set of filesystems (use with -a)  -r, --read-only         mount the filesystem read-only (same as -o ro)  -t, --types <list>      limit the set of filesystem types
      --source <src>      explicitly specifies source (path, label, uuid)
      --target <target>   explicitly specifies mountpoint  -v, --verbose           say what is being done  -w, --rw, --read-write  mount the filesystem read-write (default)

  -h, --help     display this help and exit  -V, --version  output
 version information and exit

 Source:  -L, --label <label>     synonym for LABEL=<label>  -U, --uuid
 <uuid>       synonym for UUID=<uuid>  LABEL=<label>          
 specifies device by filesystem label  UUID=<uuid>            
 specifies device by filesystem UUID  PARTLABEL=<label>       specifies
 device by partition label  PARTUUID=<uuid>         specifies device by
 partition UUID  <device>                specifies device by path 
 <directory>             mountpoint for bind mounts (see --bind/rbind) 
 <file>                  regular file for loopdev setup

 Operations:  -B, --bind              mount a subtree somewhere else
 (same as -o bind)  -M, --move              move a subtree to some
 other place  -R, --rbind             mount a subtree and all submounts
somewhere else  --make-shared           mark a subtree as shared 
 --make-slave            mark a subtree as slave  --make-private          mark a subtree as private  --make-unbindable       mark a subtree as
 unbindable  --make-rshared          recursively mark a whole subtree
 as shared  --make-rslave           recursively mark a whole subtree as
 slave  --make-rprivate         recursively mark a whole subtree as
 private  --make-runbindable      recursively mark a whole subtree as
 unbindable
```

Comment: possibly try afp; I use bookmarks on my system so the 3 TB MyCloud is accessible in either Nautilus or Caja.  Public on my system is identified as afp://userid@servername.local/Public